# JavaFX Tab text color Animation

Tags: java, css, animation, javafx

Please, explain me, how to fix the lack of animation

The tab text must be all of this hexadecimal colors:

private final String[] textColors = {
"#FF0000", "#FF3300", "#FF6600", "#FF9900", "#FFCC00", "#FFFF00", "#CCFF00", "#99FF00",
"#66FF00", "#33FF00", "#00FF00", "#00FF33", "#00FF66", "#00FF99", "#00FFCC", "#00FFFF",
"#00CCFF", "#0099FF", "#0066FF", "#0033FF", "#0000FF", "#3300FF", "#6600FF", "#9900FF",
"#CC00FF", "#FF00FF"
};

Java Tab animating method

```
private void tabPaneTabAndTabTextColorAnimation() {
        for (Tab tab : tabPane.getTabs()) {
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
            timeline.setAutoReverse(false);

            double time;

            for (int i = 0; i < textColors.length; i++) {
                time = i * 0.08;

                KeyValue textKeyValue = new KeyValue(tab.styleProperty(),
                        "-fx-text-fill: " + textColors[i] + ";");

                KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(time), textKeyValue);

                timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
            }

            timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            timeline.play();
        }
    }
```

There is no CSS that changes it, please help

I was trying to make something with CSS stylesheet, but it's not helping.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a stylesheet with a custom looked up color, or you can format a stylesheet using a data url and apply a new version of that each time you need to change the style.

The CSS rules for styling tabs are in the [`modena.css`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css#L1623).  The CSS structure is also documented in the [JAVA CSS reference](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tabpane).

Although the solution using a looked-up color relies on an inline stylesheet defined in a data URL in this example, the stylesheet for the looked-up color solution (`TAB_LABEL_CSS`) could be defined externally instead.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class AnimatedTabApp extends Application {
    private final String[] textColors = {
            "#FF0000", "#FF3300", "#FF6600", "#FF9900",
            "#FFCC00", "#FFFF00", "#CCFF00", "#99FF00",
            "#66FF00", "#33FF00", "#00FF00", "#00FF33",
            "#00FF66", "#00FF99", "#00FFCC", "#00FFFF",
            "#00CCFF", "#0099FF", "#0066FF", "#0033FF",
            "#0000FF", "#3300FF", "#6600FF", "#9900FF",
            "#CC00FF", "#FF00FF"
    };

    private static final String TAB_LABEL_CSS =
            """
            data:text/css,
            .root {
                -my-tab-label-color: red;
            }
            .tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab > .tab-container > .tab-label {
                -fx-text-fill: -my-tab-label-color;
            }
            .tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab {
                -fx-base: #3c3f4a;
            }
            """;

    private static final String TAB_LABEL_CSS_FORMATTABLE =
            """
            data:text/css,
            .tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab > .tab-container > .tab-label {
                -fx-text-fill: %s;
            }
            .tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab {
                -fx-base: #3c3f4a;
            }
            """;

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(
                createTab("Apple",  Color.PALEGREEN),
                createTab("Orange", Color.PAPAYAWHIP),
                createTab("Banana", Color.LIGHTYELLOW)
        );

        tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(
                TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE
        );

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        for (int i = 0; i < textColors.length; i++) {
            final int finalI = i;
            KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
                    Duration.seconds(i * .08),
                    // color change mechanism using a looked up color
                    e -> tabPane.setStyle(
                            "-my-tab-label-color: " + textColors[finalI] + ";"
                    )

// alternate color change mechanism using a formattable style sheet                     
//                    e -> tabPane.getStylesheets().setAll(
//                            TAB_LABEL_CSS_FORMATTABLE.formatted(
//                                    textColors[finalI]
//                            )
//                    )
            );

            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(TAB_LABEL_CSS);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        timeline.play();
    }

    private static Tab createTab(String name, Color color) {
        return new Tab(
                name,
                new Rectangle(
                        200, 100,
                        color
                )
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

#### FAQ

> why not use lookup() to get the "tab-label"?

[`lookup()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup(java.lang.String)) depends on the current structure of the scene graph, which is inherently unstable.

The scene graph can change as new tabs can be added and existing tabs can be removed.  The initialization of the scene graph is also deferred lazily in some cases for controls until the controls are attached to the scene graph, the skin associated with the control is initialized and CSS and layout passes have occurred.

I advise using stylesheets rather than lookup methods when possible.

> Surely it would be easier just to set the Graphic of the Tab to a Label, and just style the Label directly.

Using a [`graphic`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#graphicProperty) to add an animated label or text to a tab is also a valid approach.

Which approach is easier or better (the stylesheet-based approach in this answer or the proposed approach using a graphic), I think, just depends on personal experience and opinion.

If desired, an additional answer detailing the graphic approach could be added - well at least it could if the currently closed question receives enough reopen votes.

Comment: Surely it would be easier just to set the Graphic of the Tab to a Label, and just style the Label directly.  Instead of trying to reach into the CSS structure of the Tab skin and manipulate it this way.  Otherwise, why not use lookup() to get the "tab-label"?

Comment: @DaveB added a FAQ section to address follow-up questions.

Comment: I mostly agree.  Philosophically, I see the built-in Label-like structure of the Tab header to be a convenience feature.  Use it as long as it's convenient, and then don't.  Putting your own Label in the graphic feels more like a direct approach that requires way less arcane knowledge about the Modena structure behind the Tab skin.